# How to disable Media Library uploads for non-Admin users?

Tags: admin, media-library, permissions

I am working on a clients site, one of the features they want is for his **Editors** or **Authors** to only be able to select existing images to insert into Posts from the Media Library.

So looking at the media manager/upload screen below, is it possible to make the `Upload Files` tab to only be visible to `Admin Users` and also to make the `Media Library` shown by Default when this Dialog is shown?

[image]

Comment: You may want to check out [the Adminimize plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/), there are a variety of different options that may fit your needs.

Comment: This plugin does just hide it with CSS. When I open up the developers tools or FireBug (or whatever browser you use), you can simply remove `display: none;` and can access everything.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125669/disable-media-library-tab-for-non-admins-in-uploader-screen

Answer (score 17):

Here are 2 methods to disable all uploading for users that are not administrators:

## Method 1:

Remove the `upload_files` capability from the roles you do not want to be able to upload.

e.g. removing it from author role:

```php
$role = get_role( 'author' );
$role->remove_cap( 'upload_files' );
```

This is saved to the database so it should only happen once, not on every page load. Removing it from the editor role should be the same albeit with the obvious modification.

Removing the capability will have the desired effect, but it may have additional effects you may not find so desirable, the only way to be sure is to test

## Method 2

Consider this code. It uses the `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` filter to check the user has admin status, and aborts the upload if they do not. It relies on only administrators and above having `manage_options`.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Admin Only Uploads
 * Description: Prevents Uploads from non-admins
 * Author: TJNowell
 * Author URI: https://tomjn.com
 * Version: 1.0
 */

function tomjn_only_upload_for_admin( $file ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        $file['error'] = 'You can\'t upload images without admin privileges!';
    }
    return $file;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'tomjn_only_upload_for_admin' );
```

You can make use of this filter to be more specific than upload_file, e.g. preventing the upload of images, and only images, but allowing audio, etc

Comment: Doesn't this remove the entire media library?

Comment: Hence method #2

Comment: Method #2 works like a charm! My setup: some images are uploaded by the admin, while other users can only view the admin's images and cannot upload their own. Cheers!

Comment: my client keep uploading the wrong file types (png, bmp !). Can is topped them using these mime types but still allow myself to upload .PNGs?

Comment: @v3nt that's a new question, you should ask it on the site not in a comment

Comment: @TomJNowell already have and thought if directed at those familiar with this area hey might know. D.

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for this snippet, but it seems to block themes and plugins from being uploaded too, not just media files uploads. Any idea on how to make this snippet block ONLY media library uploads? Thanks!

Comment: @JesseNickles I think you've misunderstood, why would you want to prevent editors and authors from uploading images, yet allow them to upload themes and plugins? Only administrators can do that. My answer blocks uploads for non-admin users, are you saying that administrators are unable to upload plugins/themes with my plugin? If you do indeed want editors/authors to upload themes and plugins, but not upload images, then your needs do not match the question that was asked, and your question is new and separate from this

Comment: even then, did you not try method 1?

Comment: We are testing disabling media uploads on staging sites when staging sites are mirroring media uploads from production. We removed the user-level condition in your script and it works fine, but also prevents plugins/themes from being installed too. I found another question that might be the same one I have, if you wouldn't mind answering there (if you know a solution) I would appreciate it! https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194655/disable-drag-and-upload-in-media-library

Comment: I see, your situation is not the same as the question that was asked here, you should have asked a new question instead of leaving a comment. I strongly recommend you click the ask question button in the top right corner, and no that question you linked to is not the same as what you described, it's only loosely related because it involves uploads and the media library

Comment: Sometimes it's difficult to know when a new question is appropriate, sorry. We ended up moving forward with symlinks instead: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/408075/152624