# How to disable drag-and-drop upload function in Media Library?

Tags: ajax, javascript, uploads, media

Does any one knows a valid/standard way to disable drag and upload when accessing the media library in the admin area? In order to make this sense to you, I'm building a multisite and user of sub-site cannot upload media files but they can view.

I can remove their capability 'upload_file' but that would completely remove the media experience.

So far this is what I've got:

```
add_action('admin_init','disable_drag_upload');
function disable_drag_upload() {

    wp_deregister_script( 'wp-plupload' );
}
```

.. but that would skip the media library content.

Comment: If a user can not upload files, you shouldn't give him/her `upload_file` capability. I think that is a must, not an option. Then you can create a custom page to display the media files, nothing stop you, but a user with a capability that he/she can not perform is actually a very bad approach; it can give more headache than happiness; who knows when any other piece of code based on capabilities and will cause conflicts with your intention. I hope you understand my point.

Comment: @cybmeta Thanks for the great insights! This seems to be the proper way to deal with my situation as it would give the network peace of mind that no-one can bypass uploading files. As long as none of the plugins installed skipped checking the capability. It did also justify the 'upload_file' as it stands by its name.

Comment: But I wouldn't consider that approach for now as it needs more time in development, considering there are a lot of areas affecting the removal of `upload_file`, means customizing them all. That's the standard approach but not practical as it would take re-inventing what's already been designed. It's worth suggesting to the core to add something like `view_file` capability though, but until that time `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` provides a valid way atm.

Comment: Sorry, but again I don't agree with you; a `view_file` capability for media files (similar to `read` for posts) is worthless. Actually, in WordPress environment, all media files can be read and viewed by any one because the file URL is publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing upload script you can make the upload error out if the user does not have admin privileges. Like this-

```
function tomjn_only_upload_for_admin( $file ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        $file['error'] = 'You can\'t upload images without admin privileges!';
    }
    return $file;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'tomjn_only_upload_for_admin' );
```

For other possible way please follow this answer- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105558/59760

Comment: That's a fast one and I should have dig deeper in this community's questions. This might not be a direct answer since I could still attempt to drag and an upload progress is shown, which might confuses the user - if ever unintentionally dragged an image into the library. But it fixed the upload restriction. A little relief there that the other question is for Media Libraby popup, in my case it's in the media library page. Though the solution is possible to either interface. Otherwise, my question could be flagged as duplication.

Comment: We also tried Tom's script, and removed the user-level condition part, and it works great, however it also prevents users from uploading new themes/plugins too. I've asked Tom if he might answer here too in more detail. I don't think removing `upload_file` capability is appropriate either... in our case, we want users to be able to upload plugins/themes, but not any files to the Media Library, because we are testing this function on staging sites where they are mirroring /uploads/ from the production site on some servers to save disk space.

Comment: @JesseNickles your problem and this question are not the same, you need to ask a new question, you should stop commenting on questions that are loosely similar. Comments are not a place to ask new questions, they're for clarifying an answer or question