# Allow vendors on a Wordpress site to pick from a gallery of pre-selected images when choosing product's featured image

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

On my wordpress site, vendors can upload a featured image when adding a new product. Instead of having them upload images, I want them to choose from a library of images that I've picked out. Any ideas on how to implement this? Could I make a tab on the wordpress image uploader that has the public images somehow? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I would probably upload images that you want available for selection to the media library, then disable media upload capability of the user. Check out this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99248/disable-media-uploads-to-non-admin-users

Comment: Sounds like you might also want to limit which images a user can select, assuming that you don't want them to have access to your entire library of images. This link may be a good first step in achieving that: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-restrict-media-library-access-to-users-own-uploads-in-wordpress/